# Lerna issue - Convector project "'<controller>.controller.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files"

Tags: hyperledger, lerna, convector

When a Lerna command fails (calling `lerna add <package>` `lerna bootstrap`), the project may break and experience some of the following issues:

- Project folders erased
- Compile (tsc) errors like `File '/<home>/<project>/packages/<chaincode>-cc/src/<controller-name>.controller.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '/<home>/<project>/packages/<chaincode>-cc/src/'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.`

It's a Lerna issue but may affect Convector CLI generated projects, since it's a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It usually happens when a package is imported incorrectly (it may happen due to automatically importing packages with VS Code, which usually set the packages wrong)

For example:

```js
import { <controller>Controller } from '../../../<controller>-cc/src';
```

This will throw errors when trying to resolve packages.

The way to solve it is by fixing the import path like:

```js
import { <controller>Controller } from '<controller>-cc';
```

Then clean things and refresh packages.

```sh
lerna clean
# Remove the root node_modules folder
npm i
```